# anaconda-navigator is not opening

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, conda

I was using anaconda-navigator normally, but my pc crashed and I reset. Now, I get this error when I type anaconda-navigator in the linux mint console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/acer/anaconda3/bin/anaconda-navigator", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/acer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/app/main.py", line 99, in main
    from anaconda_navigator.utils.logs import clean_logs
  File "/home/acer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/utils/logs.py", line 18, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.config import (LOG_FILENAME, LOG_FOLDER,
  File "/home/acer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/config/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.config.main import CONF
  File "/home/acer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/config/main.py", line 90, in <module>
    raw_mode=True,
  File "/home/acer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/config/user.py", line 221, in __init__
    self.load_from_ini()
  File "/home/acer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/config/user.py", line 279, in load_from_ini
    self.read(self.filename(), encoding='utf-8')
  File "/home/acer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 696, in read
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "/home/acer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 1014, in _read
    for lineno, line in enumerate(fp, start=1):
  File "/home/acer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x84 in position 1: invalid start byte
```

How I resolve this? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing anaconda log files:

```
anaconda-navigator --reset
```

Then check you have `/home/$USER/.anaconda`. If yes, delete it:

```
rm -rf /home/$USER/.anaconda
```

Source: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/7256

Comment: I tried anaconda-navigator --reset but the same message appears

Comment: I tried to remove anaconda and reinstall but same... ;(

Comment: Try this: `conda install anaconda-clean`, then: `conda-clean --yes` (same source)